How to opt out from colour adjustment for dark mode in PencilKit and PKCanvasView?
When using PencilKit and PKCanvasView all colours are automatically adjusted for light and dark modes. Like in the Notes app, the black ink becomes white in dark mode.
While reading Advanced PencilKit on Kodeco I came across this:

One other thing to be mindful of is that users can turn on dark mode. By default, colors in the PencilKit canvas adjust based on dark mode settings. Think about preventing automatic color changes for apps where users draw on top of a PDS or photo. This makes sure the markup remains visible.

And the tutorial ends on that cliffhanger . How do I do this? How to properly opt out of this behaviour?

I believe that the problem can be solved by just sticking with one type of colour set (like .light).
I've found two ways of solving this. One is to always convert colours using convertColor(_:from:to:). I've tried it unsuccessfully as even if I managed to adapt all the ink colours properly, still the canvas kept changing them automatically when the user switched colour modes on the iPad.
Second (working) option is I've just set the overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light for the PKCanvasView and didn't touch anything else. BUT that is a one hacky way of doing things...
Does anybody know a proper way of opting out of automatic colour changes in PencilKit?

Why is using overrideUserInterfaceStyle hacky?

I consider it hacky because it doesn't work with colours directly. It just sets to present them in .light. I don't know how those colours are stored, coded/encoded, etc. And, I'm afraid this will lead to bugs in the future.
